# How to add macro to progress bar

Tags: excel, statusbar, vba

I have this Macro that makes a progress bar in the status bar, but I can not get how to add a macro to it.

i.e if I have a sub, say, Sub LongExacutionTime() how do I apply `ShowProgress` to it

I tried changing `'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") '<– Replace this line with your own   code to do something`  to this

`Call LongExacutionTimeLongExacutionTime` but it executes `LongExacutionTimeLongExacutionTime` 10 times (once for each iteration of the loop)

This seems like it should be simple to get and maybe it is but I am not getting it

any insight into this is appriciated

Thanks

```
Sub ShowProgress()
Dim strBar As String
Dim lngLoop As Long


'make StatusBar visible
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
strBar = String(0, ChrW(&H25A0)) & String(10, ChrW(&H25A1))
Application.StatusBar = strBar & "Starting…"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:0:01")

 For lngLoop = 1 To 1
     strBar = String(lngLoop, ChrW(&H25A0)) & String(10 - lngLoop, ChrW(&H25A1))
     Application.StatusBar = strBar & " Processing…"
    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") '<– Replace this line with your own   code to do something        
   Next

'Relinquish the StatusBar
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Sub ShowProgress(strMessage As String)

    'make StatusBar visible
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = strMessage

End Sub

Public Sub LongExecutionTime()

    'About to start
    Call ShowProgress("Starting...")

    'Run some other code.  I've put a wait of 5 seconds in so you can see the status bar saying "Starting..."
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    'Process some stuff
    Call ShowProgress("Processing...")

    'Run some other code.  I've put a wait of 5 seconds in so you can see the status bar saying "Processing..."
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Call ShowProgress("FinishingUp..")
    'Same wait
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'Turn off StatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. That helped alot.

Comment: Also, if Application.screenupdating is set to false, you might want to add a DoEvents everytime when showing Statusbar.